# vSphere 5.1 SSO upgrade issue

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, single-sign-on

I´m having issues upgrading VMware vSphere Infrastructure from 5.1.0.1123961 to 5.1.1474365. 
First I ran into the issue described in the VMware KB 2046318 (Installing vCenter Single Sign-On fails with Error 20003 (2046318)). To summarize the issue, after upgrading SSO the SSO server did not start, logs were not writing and Windows UAC was not working (therefor everything depending on UAC was not working either).
Following the steps in the KB 2046318 I was able to upgrade the SSO successful.

Here is what I did so far ...

1.
Creating a SSO Backup using the “Generate vCenter Single Sign On backup bundle” shortcut.

2.
Uninstalling vCenter SSO

3.
Shutting down all VMware Services on the Server (Virtual Storage Console for VMware vSphere Server, VMware Snapshot Provider, VMware USB Arbitration Service, VMware vCenter Inventory Service, VMware vCenter Orchestrator Configuration, VMware vCenter Orchestrator Server, VMware VirtualCenter Management Webservices, VMware VirtualCenter Server,  VMware vSphere Profile-Driven Storage Service, VMware vSphere Update Manager Service, VMware vSphere Update Manager UFA Service)

4.
Renaming the C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\jre1 directory

5.
Starting the autorun.exe using run as administrator

6.
Installing the Single Sign on the Server in recovery mode. This is descripted in VMware KB 2034928  (Backing up and restoring the vCenter Single Sign-On (SSO) 5.1 configuration (2034928)). Choose during the installation: “Recover installed instance of vCenter Single Sign On from a backup The Installation was successful.

What I noticed is that looking at the SSO webservice on https://vcenter.domain:7444/lookupservice/sdk. I get a Tomcat HTTP Status 404 error (The requested resource is not available). On a working SSO webservice I see a XML soap webservice status.

Due to the fact that the webservice is not available I cannot install / upgrade the Inventory Service. THe lookupserver.log tells me that there is a issue with the Connection the the database. But i´m stucked here ....

The lookupserver.log Looks like this

```
[2014-06-30 15:27:49,345 DEBUG opID= ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  com.vmware.vim.lookup.impl.DbStorage] Successfully loaded JDBC driver for DB type:Mssql
[2014-06-30 15:27:49,376 DEBUG opID= ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  com.vmware.vim.lookup.impl.DbStorage] DB connection pool created
[2014-06-30 15:27:49,392 DEBUG opID= ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  com.vmware.vim.lookup.impl.DbStorage] Executing SELECT CONFIG_VALUE FROM LS_CONFIGURATION WHERE CONFIG_KEY = ?
[2014-06-30 15:27:49,407 DEBUG opID= ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  com.vmware.vim.lookup.impl.DbStorage] Error executing statement SELECT CONFIG_VALUE FROM LS_CONFIGURATION WHERE CONFIG_KEY = ?
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'LS_CONFIGURATION'.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
```

and the ssoadminserver.log Looks like this

ssoAdminServer.log

```
[2014-06-30 15:26:25,527 INFO  opID= localhost-startStop-1  com.vmware.vim.sso.admin.server.ims.impl.DefaultCommandExecutor] Establishing connection with the Castle server - target: LocalJvmAccessTarget
[2014-06-30 15:26:25,746 INFO  opID= localhost-startStop-1  com.vmware.vim.sso.admin.server.ims.impl.DefaultCommandExecutor] Connection with Castle server was successfully configured.
[2014-06-30 15:26:26,401 INFO  opID= DomainKeepAliveThread  com.vmware.vim.sso.admin.server.impl.KeepAlive] KeepAlive thread started.
[2014-06-30 15:27:25,676 ERROR opID= pool-3-thread-1  com.vmware.vim.vmomi.server.impl.ValidationStartTask] Failed to start activation validation 1 of 1, failing request
com.rsa.common.SystemException: Unexpected exception
```

Comment: Have you logged a case for this with VMWare? vCenter is a paid product so therefore you have a support contract and vendor support should always be called on before coming to SF.